# Cant Load library GT SUMMARY in r

Tags: r, namespaces, command-line-interface, gtsummary, trial

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gtsummary’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘cli’ 3.1.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.1.1 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘gtsummary’ was built under R version 4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Just try `install.packages("cli")` to update the package to the latest version.